# AndEngine disable pool

Tags: android, game-engine, andengine

Good day,

i have an application build with andEngine,
There is no such big amount of objects to use pool of objects, but as i found AndEngine put the Sprite to the pool by default.

Every ~0.6 seconds by default this function

```
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed)
```

from PoolUpdateHanlder.class is called.

Using pool takes time and memory (after some time application become too large) and i want to disable it. Is it any way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Are you creating a PoolUpdateHandler yourself?

Btw, you know there are the AndEngine forums?

Comment: Yes, i know that there is a forum and first of all i post my question there. No, i don't create anything that contain "pool" =)

Comment: there is a topic in the forum: [link](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post22380.html#p22380)